# "directions that in which"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, relative-pronouns

The sentence: "In this article, we outline the most telling features in light of these three main directions **that in which** Wi-Fi technologies are advancing."

What is "that" here. Is it a relative pronoun? If then, why they used two relative pronouns. What is the difference between just "in which"?

Comment: Can you give the link for the source, please?

Comment: @AIQ I think it's not that helpful but anyway the source is : W. Sun et al., “Wi-Fi Could Be Much More,” IEEE Commun. Mag., vol. 52, no. 11, Nov. 2014, pp. 22–29

Comment: It looks like an error or an editing oversight.